# How to kill a particular activity?

Tags: android

When my android app is started, main activity is launched. It displays a full screen image for 5 seconds, and then it  jumps to another activity using intent. What i want is to kill the main activity, so that when user presses the back button of navigation bar, instead of opening main activity, the app gets closed.

One more thing:- i don't want to keep on destroying previous activities. I just want to kill that one activity(namely main activity), just after the intent is sent to new activity, Because i will be adding more activities.

We can say that my true purpose is destruction of main activity, and making the next activity(out of all other activities) as a activity through which the app can be leaved using back button of navigation bar.

I am not able to properly explain my problem in words, but please try to figure out my problem what what all i have mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `MainAcitivity` ,call the second activity like this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,<your second activity.class>;
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful. It works properly as i want it to.

Answer (score 5):

I would add

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml, specifically in the MainActivity definition

Comment: Sorry, it will keep on killing previous activities which i don't want to happen.

Comment: you have to add this only to the activity that you don't want to store in the stack, that is, MainActivity

Comment: Ok! I got it. This will clear history only for main activity. Correct?

Comment: this means that the activity won't be added in the stack, i.e. when you press back in the following opened activity the app closes as you need

Answer (score 3):

To kill `Activity` you have to use method `finish();`

In `MainActivity` in code, where you are starting next activity add `finish();`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: I already got the answer to my question but thank for telling me the use of finish()

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to achieve is called a splash screen.

In your main activity start another activity and if the user presses back on another activity, simply call o finish on main activity. Destroying parent activities before child is sort of messy.

I'd recommend googling splash screens through cold app booting.